# Formula to find the next min value in a field

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

min(A) is 12

how to find the next min(A) which is 14 with a formula?
next min (A) 14 - price 443

Comment: Look into the excel small function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your data:

```
=SMALL(A2:A6,2)
```

and to get the price:

```
=INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(SMALL(A2:A6,2),A2:A6,0))
```

In the above `MATCH()` gets the row and `INDEX()` gets the price.